# Ubuntu Server can not access Internet

Tags: 12.04, networking, server

I have a problem that I have been working for 2 days now and had tried various troubleshooting techniques but have yet to find a solution.  So to my problem.... I have a Ubuntu Server. was working fine then I installed DHCP Server, even before i configured it the server could not access the internet.  Access inside the LAN is available but not anything outside the LAN.  Please help? # AzkerM Here it is

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.34 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.34 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.34 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Kernel IP routing table

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 br0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 br0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

cat /etc/resolv.conf

```
Generated by NetworkManager
domain MiracleDC
search MiracleDC
nameserver 192.168.2.3
```

Comment: Hi! Can you please elaborate more in-detail such as what happens when you try to access internet?? what type of errors you're receiving while posting the output for `ifconfig` & `route -n` also `cat /etc/resolv.conf`. Please also explain the DHCP server that you've installed, is it within the Ubuntu server, do you already have a router/device issuing DHCP... etc.

Comment: @AzkerM, thank you for your reply.  I will surely include them soon. I installed the DHCP Server within the Ubuntu Server.  After completing the installation BEFORE configuring I notice that Ubuntu Server can not access internet.  But the Server can be accessed by any PC/Server from LAN.  I removed the DHCP Server from Ubuntu but still the problem persists. I believe During the Installation something might have got changed but I can't seems to figure out what it is... as a side not I have a Windows DC at the moment offering DHCP & DNS on the same network

Comment: You don't really need a Win DC to issue DHCP / DNS as this can be achieved easily with a router. So you basically assign static IP's or if by any chance the router handles DHCP? :)

Comment: Router & the Switch do not assign IP's.  All are done through the Windows Server. my sole purpose is to switch from Windows to Linux.  and I would like to use the Server to assign the IP's as the users are authenticating as well. I am planing to deploy Remote Access as well among many other service. Right now I am stuck at this simple yet Very difficult Step & worse is that I have already spend 2 days on this. Very frustrating.

Comment: If I have a DC environment where users authenticating the AD, I would definitely let the Windows handle all DHCP, DNS requests despite the Ubuntu. May be I would use Ubuntu to handle internet request routed through using certain Apps. But that's me. Okay! Let us focus on getting internet. I would need those outputs to advise further. :)

Comment: I do agree with you now.  Its much easier than Ubuntu :) Thank you for looking into this issue

Comment: I see where the problem is lying now. Assuming that you've added your DC IP with the attribute `nameserver`.. Please change it to `nameserver 127.0.0.1` or either to a public DNS. Create a DNS entry with PTR at your DC to handle requests and lookups. Editing the `resolv.conf` without an acknowledgment is not a good idea if you have. Also, I see there's a virtual bridge device hanging on your Ubuntu server.

Comment: Yes.  I have a virtual bridge as I am running a another windows file server inside ubuntu on KVM Virtual Manager. So what I should do is to change the nameserver to 127.0.0.1 in my interface card entry? can simplify.. sosrry as I am a noooobee :)

Comment: Ideally that should start resolving internet requests. The only thing I see is on your `resolv.conf` file where a private IP is defined. you can either use `nameserver 127.0.0.1` or `nameserver 8.8.8.8`. Give it a try and see.

Comment: When I change the resolv.conf to 127.0.0.1  & restarted the Server it change back to 192.168.2.3 :( i went to sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/original & /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base but there is nothing there too

Comment: BTW when I get this one as well nilanga@Miracle-Adventure:~$ nslookup google.com
Server:         192.168.2.3
Address:        192.168.2.3#53

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find the solution for the problem... So far it's working.  I removed Bind9:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove bind9
```

But that entirely did not do the trick. I needed to change the Network Manager settings:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

and make sure it's like this:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
dns=dnsmasq

no-auto-default=00:10:18:77:5E:46,00:23:AE:6A:45:9B,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

(I changed the last from true to false)

Somehow the GUI Network Manager was causing the Ubuntu Server not access the internet.

Thank you for all your inputs, without them I would not have been able to find the solution

now running 
`cat /etc/resolv.conf` gives me:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
search google.com
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```